# Still Having Issues Displaying Select Option in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the selected option from an HTML select box to display on a row in a table element in HTML. I know I asked this question earlier, but after updating the code and trying to make it work, I still can't figure it out. This code generates an HTML form called Create Event.html which enables a user to create a calendar event. This code from Create Event.js is supposed to generate another form within Create Event.html to set a reminder, such as when to send the reminder and who to send it to. After setting a reminder, it shows up on a list of reminders that you can continue to add to. [image: Should have "Before" on "On the day" in the When column] There should be "Before" or "On the day" in the When column, but it doesn't appear. I continue to get this error whenever I run the code: "Uncaught Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')" at line 223. I'm not sure what the undefined object is: I believe it is either this.num or this.unit, but I may be wrong. I appreciate any help you can give.

```js
var br = document.createElement("br");

const dom = {
    $(id) {
        if (typeof id === 'string')
            return document.getElementById(id)
        return id
    },
    add_event(el, type, f) {
        el = dom.$(el)
        if (!el.$events)
            el.$events = {}
        el.$events[type] = (el.$events[type] || []).push(f)
        el.addEventListener(type, f)
    },
    add_script(js) {
        if (!js)
            return
        var script = document.createElement('script')
        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript')
        script.text = js
        document.head.appendChild(script)
        document.head.removeChild(script)
    },
    append_text(el, text) {
        el = dom.$(el)
        if (text)
            el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text))
        return el
    },
    at_bottom() {
        return window.pageYOffset > document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight - 10
    },
    children_height(el) {
        let h = 0
        for (var i=0; i<el.children.length; i++)
            h += el.children[i].offsetHeight
        return h
    },
    el(tag, properties) {
        let el = document.createElement(tag)
        for (const p in properties)
            if (!dom.set(el, p, properties))
                el[p] = properties[p]
                //el.setAttribute(p, properties[p])
        return el
    },
    empty(el) {
        el = dom.$(el)
        while (el.firstChild)
            el.removeChild(el.firstChild)
        return el
    },
    extract_js(html) {
        let js = ''
        html = html.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gi, function(all, code) {
            js += code + '\n'
            return ''
        })
        return {html:html, js:js}
    },
    pos(el) {
        el = dom.$(el)
        let r = el.getBoundingClientRect()
        return {x:r.left + window.pageXOffset, y:r.top + window.pageYOffset}
    },
    remove_class(el, c) {
        el.classList.remove(c)
        if (el.classList.length == 0)
            el.removeAttribute('class')
    },
    remove_events(el, type) {
        el = dom.$(el)
        if (!el.$events)
            return
        el.$events[type].forEach(f => el.removeEventListener(type, f))
        delete el.$events[type]
    },
    replace(el, html) {
        el = dom.$(el)
        let x = dom.extract_js(html)
        let is_tr = x.html.startsWith('<tr')
        let d = dom.el(is_tr ? 'table' : 'div', {html:x.html})
        el.parentNode.replaceChild(is_tr ? d.querySelector('tr'): d.firstChild, el)
        if (x.js)
            dom.add_script(x.js)
    },
    rotate(el, deg) {
        el = dom.$(el)
        let rotated = el.style.transform
        el.style.transform = rotated ? '' : 'rotate('+(deg?deg:'90')+'deg)'
        return !rotated
    },
    set(el, p, properties) {
        if (p.startsWith('data-') || p == 'for' || p == 'required') {
            el.setAttribute(p, properties[p])
            return true
        }
        switch(p) {
        case 'before':
            properties.before.parentNode.insertBefore(el, properties.before)
            return true
        case 'children':
            for (var i=0; i<properties.children.length; i++)
                el.appendChild(properties.children[i])
            return true;
        case 'classes':
            if (properties.classes)
                el.classList.add(...properties.classes)
            return true
        case 'events':
            for (const e in properties.events)
                el.addEventListener(e, properties.events[e])
            return true
        case 'html':
            el.innerHTML = properties[p]
            return true
        case 'parent':
            properties.parent.appendChild(el)
            return true
        case 'parentFirst':
            properties.parentFirst.insertBefore(el, properties.parentFirst.firstChild)
            return true
        case 'styles':
            dom.set_styles(el, properties.styles)
            return true
        case 'text':
            dom.append_text(el, properties.text)
            return true
        }
        return false
    },
    set_html(el, html) {
        el = dom.$(el)
        let x = dom.extract_js(html)
        el.innerHTML = x.html
        if (x.js)
            dom.add_script(x.js)
        return el
    },
    set_style(el, style, value) {
        el = dom.$(el)
        if (typeof value != 'string') {
            if (dom.Styles[style] && value) {
                var map = dom.Styles[style].split(' ')
                value = (Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value]).map(function(val, i) {
                    if (!map[i]) return ''
                    return typeof val  == 'number' ? map[i].replace('@', val) : val
                }).join(' ')
            }
        }
        el.style[style] = value
        return el
    },
    set_styles(el, styles) {
        el = dom.$(el)
        for (const style in styles)
            dom.set_style(el, style, styles[style])
        return el
    },
    size(el) {
        if (el === window)
            return {x: window.innerWidth, y: window.innerHeight}
        if (el === document)
            el = document.body
        else
            el = dom.$(el)
        let r = el.getBoundingClientRect()
        return {x: r.width, y: r.height}
    },
    Styles: {
        left: '@px', top: '@px', bottom: '@px', right: '@px',
        width: '@px', height: '@px', maxWidth: '@px', maxHeight: '@px', minWidth: '@px', minHeight: '@px',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(@, @, @)', backgroundSize: '@px', backgroundPosition: '@px @px', color: 'rgb(@, @, @)',
        fontSize: '@px', letterSpacing: '@px', lineHeight: '@px', clip: 'rect(@px @px @px @px)',
        margin: '@px @px @px @px', marginBottom: '@px', marginLeft: '@px', marginRight: '@px', marginTop: '@px',
        padding: '@px @px @px @px', paddingBottom: '@px', paddingLeft: '@px', paddingRight: '@px', paddingTop: '@px',
        border: '@px @ rgb(@, @, @) @px @ rgb(@, @, @) @px @ rgb(@, @, @)',
        borderWidth: '@px @px @px @px', borderStyle: '@ @ @ @', borderColor: 'rgb(@, @, @) rgb(@, @, @) rgb(@, @, @) rgb(@, @, @)',
        textIndent: '@px', borderRadius: '@px @px @px @px'
    },
    svg(properties) {
        var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
        for (const p in properties)
            if (!dom.set(el, p, properties))
                el.setAttribute(p, properties[p])
        return el;
    }
}

class ReminderWhen {
  constructor(id, num) {
    this.num = dom.$(id);
    this.num.addEventListener('change', this.on_num_change.bind(this));
    this.unit = this.num.nextElementSibling;
    this.unit.addEventListener('change', this.on_unit_change.bind(this));
    this.before = this.unit.nextElementSibling;
    this.before.addEventListener('change', this.on_before_change.bind(this));
    this.on_before_change();
    this.on_unit_change(num);
  }

  add_nums(from, to, mult, val) {
    for (let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
      let v = i * mult;
      this.num.appendChild(new Option(v, v, null, v == val));
    }
  }

  on_before_change() {
    let on_the_day = this.before.selectedIndex === 0;
    this.num.style.display = this.unit.style.display = on_the_day ? 'none' : 'inline';
    this.num.name = on_the_day ? '' : "num";
    this.unit.name = on_the_day ? '' : "unit";
    if (!on_the_day)
      this.on_num_change();
  }

  on_num_change() {
    if (this.num.options.length === 0)
            return;
    let one = this.num.options[this.num.selectedIndex].value === "1";
    for (let i = 0; i < this.unit.options.length; i++) {
      let text = this.unit.options[i].text;
      if (one) {
        if (text.endsWith('s'))
          this.unit.options[i].text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
      } else
      if (!text.endsWith('s'))
        this.unit.options[i].text = text + 's';
    }
  }

  on_unit_change(event) {
    let val = typeof event === 'object' ? this.num.options[this.num.selectedIndex].text : event;
    this.num.options.length = 0;
    let unit = this.unit.options[this.unit.selectedIndex].value;
    if (unit === 'day' || unit === 'week')
      this.add_nums(1, 10, 1, val);
    else if (unit === 'hour')
      this.add_nums(1, 23, 1, val);
    else
      this.add_nums(0, 3, 30, val);
    this.on_num_change();
  }
}

function create_reminder() {
  let form = document.createElement("form");
  form.setAttribute("method", "post");
  form.setAttribute("action", "");
  form.setAttribute("id", "reminder_form");

  // When
  let reminder_status_label = document.createElement("label");
  reminder_status_label.setAttribute("for", "reminder_status");
  reminder_status_label.innerHTML = "When";

  let reminder_status = document.createElement("select");
  reminder_status.setAttribute("name", "reminder_status");
  reminder_status.setAttribute("id", "reminder-status-sel");

  let reminder_status_1 = document.createElement("option");
  reminder_status_1.setAttribute("value", "on-the-day");
  reminder_status_1.setAttribute("id", "on-the-day");
  reminder_status_1.innerHTML = "On the day";

  let reminder_status_2 = document.createElement("option");
  reminder_status_2.setAttribute("value", "before");
  reminder_status_2.setAttribute("id", "before");
  reminder_status_2.innerHTML = "Before";

  // Note
  let note_label = document.createElement("label");
  note_label.setAttribute("for", "note");
  note_label.innerHTML = "Note";

  let note = document.createElement("textarea");
  note.setAttribute("name", "note");
  note.setAttribute("id", "reminder-note");
  note.setAttribute("row", "10");
  note.setAttribute("col", "60");

  // Send to
  let send_to_label = document.createElement("label");
  send_to_label.setAttribute("for", "send-to");
  send_to_label.innerHTML = "Send to Guest";

  let send_to = document.createElement("select");
  send_to.setAttribute("name", "send-to");

  let blank = document.createElement("option");
  blank.setAttribute("value", "--");

  let email_1 = document.createElement("option");
  email_1.setAttribute("value", "naa1234@cohousing.site");
  email_1.innerHTML = "naa1234@cohousing.site";

  let email_2 = document.createElement("option");
  email_2.setAttribute("value", "sd4567@cohousing.site");
  email_2.innerHTML = "sd4567@cohousing.site";

  let email_3 = document.createElement("option");
  email_3.setAttribute("value", "mk7890@cohousing.site");
  email_3.innerHTML = "mk7890@cohousing.site";

  let email_4 = document.createElement("option");
  email_4.setAttribute("value", "jk0123@cohousing.site");
  email_4.innerHTML = "jk0123@cohousing.site";

  let email_5 = document.createElement("option");
  email_5.setAttribute("value", "ms3456@cohousing.site");
  email_5.innerHTML = "ms3456@cohousing.site";

  let add_reminder_btn = document.createElement("button");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("name", "add_reminder");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("id", "add-reminder-to-list-btn");
  add_reminder_btn.innerHTML = "Add";

  let cancel_reminder_btn = document.createElement("button");
  cancel_reminder_btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  cancel_reminder_btn.setAttribute("name", "cancel_reminder");
  cancel_reminder_btn.setAttribute("id", "cancel-reminder-to-list-btn");
  cancel_reminder_btn.innerHTML = "Cancel";
  cancel_reminder_btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    form.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  })

  // Form
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(reminder_status_label);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(reminder_status);
  reminder_status.appendChild(reminder_status_1);
  reminder_status.appendChild(reminder_status_2);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());

  form.appendChild(note_label);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(note);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());

  form.appendChild(send_to_label);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(send_to);
  send_to.appendChild(blank);
  send_to.appendChild(email_1);
  send_to.appendChild(email_2);
  send_to.appendChild(email_3);
  send_to.appendChild(email_4);
  send_to.appendChild(email_5);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());

  form.appendChild(add_reminder_btn);
  form.appendChild(cancel_reminder_btn);

  document.getElementById("reminder")
    .appendChild(form);

let reminder_status_sel_txt = new ReminderWhen("reminder-status-sel", 2);
}

function list_reminder() {
  let add_reminder_btn = document.createElement("button");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("name", "add_reminder");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("class", "add-reminder-btn");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("id", "add-reminder-btn");
  add_reminder_btn.innerHTML = "Add";
  add_reminder_btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    create_reminder();
  })

  let reminder_table = document.createElement("table");
  reminder_table.setAttribute("id", "reminder-table");
  let reminder_table_head = document.createElement("thead");
  reminder_table_head.setAttribute("id", "reminder-list-header");
  let reminder_table_col_1 = document.createElement("th");
  reminder_table_col_1.innerHTML = "Send to";
  let reminder_table_col_2 = document.createElement("th");
  reminder_table_col_2.innerHTML = "When";
  let reminder_table_col_3 = document.createElement("th");

  let reminder_table_body = document.createElement("tbody");
  let reminder_table_row = document.createElement("tr");
  let reminder_table_cell_1 = document.createElement("td");
  reminder_table_cell_1.setAttribute("class", "reminder-list");
  let reminder_table_cell_2 = document.createElement("td");
  reminder_table_cell_2.setAttribute("class", "reminder-list");
  reminder_table_cell_2.setAttribute("id", "reminder-when");
  let reminder_table_cell_3 = document.createElement("td");
  reminder_table_cell_3.setAttribute("class", "reminder-list");

  reminder_table_cell_1.innerHTML = "abc1234@cohousing.site";

  let edit_reminder_btn = document.createElement("button");
  edit_reminder_btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  edit_reminder_btn.setAttribute("name", "edit_reminder");
  edit_reminder_btn.setAttribute("class", "edit-delete-reminder-btns");
  edit_reminder_btn.innerHTML = "Edit";

  let delete_reminder_btn = document.createElement("button");
  delete_reminder_btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  delete_reminder_btn.setAttribute("name", "delete_reminder");
  delete_reminder_btn.setAttribute("class", "edit-delete-reminder-btns");
  delete_reminder_btn.innerHTML = "Delete";

  reminder_table.appendChild(reminder_table_head);
  reminder_table_head.appendChild(reminder_table_col_1);
  reminder_table_head.appendChild(reminder_table_col_2);
  reminder_table_head.appendChild(reminder_table_col_3);

  reminder_table.appendChild(reminder_table_body);
  reminder_table_body.appendChild(reminder_table_row);
  reminder_table_row.appendChild(reminder_table_cell_1);
  reminder_table_row.appendChild(reminder_table_cell_2);
  reminder_table_row.appendChild(reminder_table_cell_3);
  reminder_table_cell_3.appendChild(edit_reminder_btn);
  reminder_table_cell_3.appendChild(delete_reminder_btn);

  document.getElementById("reminder")
    .appendChild(add_reminder_btn);

  document.getElementById("reminder")
    .appendChild(reminder_table);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is really big and complex and doesn't seem to be doing much funcionality, I would suggest for you to study some modern javascript framework like React, even old JQuery would be good.

I tried to run your code and I got the same error Cannot read properties of undefined

`this.unit` receives in the constructor the next element after the `<select name="num">`, which is a `<br>` element, a `br` element doesn't have options, that's why you are getting this error

```
on_num_change() {
    if (this.num.options.length === 0) return;
    let one = this.num.options[this.num.selectedIndex].value === '1';
    for (let i = 0; i < this.unit.options.length; i++) { //unit.options is undefined, so it throws the error when trying to access .length
        let text = this.unit.options[i].text;
        if (one) {
            if (text.endsWith('s')) this.unit.options[i].text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
        } else if (!text.endsWith('s')) this.unit.options[i].text = text + 's';
    }
}
```